# How to set fitContainer property in ngx-horizontal-bar-chart?

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular9, ngx-charts

I am using the latest version of `ngx-charts (13.0.2)` in my angular web application and I am using horizontal bar chart in that for data summary purpose.

Here's the demos link of ngx-charts:

> https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/bar-horizontal

And here's the link of ngx-horizontal-bar-charts documentation:

> https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/v/docs-test/examples/bar-charts/horizontal-bar-chart

Now the problem is as given in the demos link, there's one option named: **fitContainer**. If i check that in demo, the chart becomes responsive on resizing. I want the exact same thing. but I don't know how to define "fitContainer" and on which basis/logic after checking that option (I show changes in developer options), the width is changing on resize.

Stackblitz is already given in document link.

Answer (score 0):

it might be a littly to late, but the "fitContainer" behaviour is the default. As the doc say for the view argument

```
"the dimensions of the chart [width, height]. If left undefined, the chart will fit to the parent container size"
```

So if you simply do not assign values to [view] this should do the trick.

Comment: I don't understand that why in the first place, they would give as it a option in their live demo! LOL

Answer (score 0):

you can try to bind the view array on window resize event.

in **component.ts**

```
// declare view params as height is static and width is dynamic.
view: any[] = [undefined, 200];

onResize(event) { 
  this.view = [event.target.innerWidth - 600, 200];
}
```

in **component.html**

```
<ngx-charts-bar-horizontal
  (window:resize)="onResize($event)" [view]="view"> 
</ngx-charts-bar-horizontal>
```